# Ionic 3 error 'collapse' is not a known element:

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

iam trying to create my own component using Ionic 3 i follow this steps

- **Step 1 - create the component using command line**

```
ionic g component collapse
```

- **Step 2 - add within app.module**

```
...
declarations: [
        CollapseComponent
    ],
...
entryComponents: [
        CollapseComponent
    ],
...
```

- **Step 3 - Trying to use the tag**

```
 collapse
```

but i have this bug.

I've tried many alternatives and nothing has worked.

- collapse.ts file
  import { Component } from '@angular/core';

  ```
  @Component({
    selector: 'collapse',
    templateUrl: 'collapse.html'
  })
  export class CollapseComponent {
    text: string;

    constructor() {
      console.log('Hello CollapseComponent Component');
      this.text = 'Hello World';
    }
  }
  ```

* component.mudule.ts file

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {PopoverComponent} from './popover/popover';
import {CollapseComponent} from './collapse/collapse';
import {IonicModule} from "ionic-angular";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        PopoverComponent,
        CollapseComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule,
    ],
    exports: [
        PopoverComponent,
        CollapseComponent
    ]
})
export class ComponentsModule {
}
```

Comment: Normally when you did "ionic g component collapse" you should see in your terminal `[OK] Generated a component named collapse!` did you have this message?

Comment: Yes, I had this message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your component like that :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'collapse',
  templateUrl: `<URL>`
})
export class CollapseComponent {

}
```

By default, component tags have a prefix like `app`. You can also try <{prefixe}-collapse>.
`selector` field is the most important

Comment: It does not work either, I tried to use the prefixes 'app' and 'ion'

Comment: import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'collapse',
  templateUrl: 'collapse.html'
})
export class CollapseComponent {

  text: string;

  constructor() {
    console.log('Hello CollapseComponent Component');
    this.text = 'Hello World';
  }

}

Comment: Check `.angular-cli.json` file and `prefix` field. By default, it's `app`. You can also check `tslint.json` file a,d `component-selector` field. It must contain `app`

Comment: Do you have an error message in your terminal or in your browser? Or dev tools?

Comment: i changed the implementation. Thanks for all